# java.lang.nosuchmethoderror:'void com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.extent htmlreporter.load xml config'

Tags: java, maven, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-java, extentreports

Getting below error while running the code,

> java.lang.nosuchmethoderror:'void
>   com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.extent htmlreporter.load xml
>   config'

Running the code in eclipse, maven project with cucumber framework, trying to configure extent report with cucumber in maven project. Configured almost everything as expected i hope, still

> 1. **Unable to generate extent report**
> 2. **Able to run the code but at the end displaying above mentioned error in junit.**
> 3. **In maven project for extent report generation, where do i need to create extent-config.xml file**(for good folder structure).

Please help me with the code....
FYI, Added 3 dependencies - cucumber extent report, extent report, extentreports cucumber4 adapter
Below is my 'TestRunner' file,

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src\\main\\java\\Features\\launch.feature", //the path of the feature files
        glue={"stepDefinition"}, //the path of the step definition files
        plugin={"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:output/report.html"},
        //format= {"pretty","html:test-outout", "json:json_output/cucumber.json", "junit:junit_xml/cucumber.xml"}, //to generate different types of reporting
        monochrome = true, //display the console output in a proper readable format
        strict = true, //it will check if any step is not defined in step definition file
        dryRun = false //to check the mapping is proper between feature file and step def file          
        ) 

public class TestRunner {

@BeforeClass
public static void before()
{
    ExtentReports extentReports = new ExtentReports(); 
    extentReports.flush();
}

@AfterClass
public static void setup()
{       
    Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("src\\main\\java\\extent-config.xml"));
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("user", System.getProperty("user.name"));
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("os", "win");
    Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("Sample test runner output message");   
}
```

}

For extent reports generation other than Feature file, Step definition file, Testrunner class, I have created extent-config.xml file. Is it enough or else i need to create other files also for extent reports.

Added dependencies for extent report generation,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: you should locate your configuration like `src\\main\\java\\extent-config.xml` in `src/main/resources` instead and do not try to load it on that path...cause it's a resource in the jar file ...so direct file access will not work. You have to use ´getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/extent-config.xml")`...

Comment: Didn't get the point, will you please elaborate.....thanks